# Attaching Excel sheet with different language font(hindi) to shapefile

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, excel, qgis-2.8, font

When I try to join a excel sheet with Hindi font to a shp file, I get '?????' as a result in those cells which has Hindi font. (Before/Aft images attached)[image: Before/After Image attached]

I tried changing the locale language to Hindi but still no relief.

I suppose I am missing the right procedure. Can anyone help me with this..

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding for your csv layer? Right click your csv layer and then `Properties > General > Data source encoding`.

Comment: @Joseph I am using a excel sheet and the 'Date source encoding' tag is bydefault set to 'UTF-8' format (greyed out). I set the same for the shapefile later from 'System' but no luck.

Comment: Are you using a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file? Have you tried exporting it to `csv` and then importing it with "Add Delimited Text Layer". There you can choose the proper encoding when importing. It also seems that your column names are not recognized correctly (they are named `Field1` etc. and your first feature contains the column names). This can be avoided with a `csv` file by choosing a "Number of header lines to discard".

Comment: @thibautg when I try converting d excelsheet to csv, then 'n' there itself d Hindi font characters disappear I tried choosing d Hindi font in office but no use. So am directly using the excelsheet and while loading excelsheet QGIS does not give d option to choose columns as field names as in delimited text.

Comment: Maybe try to save you Excel file to csv from within QGIS instead of excel. It seems that QGIS correctly recognizes the encoding, but gets confused with the Join. But I have no experience with Hindi...

Comment: Yes, you r right @thibautg I converted excel to csv in QGIS, it preserved the font. But after running the join on the resultant csv, the hindi font disappears and is replaced by '?????'. So any solution/workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the workaround/solution

Rather than using the join attribute tool, I joined using the join tool under the properties of the shapefile. It retained the Hindi characters.

Then I saved the joined shapefile as a new shapefile and while doing it set the encoding as UTF-8. Resultant shpfile retained all the Hindi characters.

I think the issue with using join attribute tool is it does not give us an option to choose encoding and its default encoding is unable to recognise the Hindi characters.

Thanks for all those who gave a thought on this issue.